# how to add date in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, chat, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

Somehow, I could add messageBubble in chat through JSQMessagesViewController.
But, I am not sure how to add "date" in method.
Could you please teach me about it ?

```
JSQMessage *message = [JSQMessage messageWithSenderId:@"user1"
                                          displayName:@"classmethod"
                                                 text:JSONDict[@"Message"][@"content"]
                                                    ];
[self.messages addObject:message];
```

[image]

Comment: Related::https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/730

Answer (score 0):

its look like like you are using old version of JSQMessageViewController this new method solve your problem

```
   JSQMessage *message = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:self.senderId                                           
senderDisplayName:self.senderDisplayName date:[NSDate date] media:item];
```